# Why mousemove() doesn't call itself while mouse isn't moving?

Tags: jquery

If you put mouse on page and press F5 then mousemove() doesn't call itself. Why? But if I'll write this:

```
$(document).on("mousemove", function(mouse) {
    console.log(mouse.clienX);
}).mousemove();
```

then mouse.clienX is indefined. Why?

How to make mousemove() to work on a loaded page without a firstly mousemoving?

Comment: Why you think that the mouse move when you refresh?

Comment: Also - shouldn't `mouse.clienX` be instead `mouse.clientX`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make mousemove() to work on a loaded page without a firstly mousemoving?

This is the real question.

Obviously `mousemove` fires when the mouse is moving. If it's not moving then it shouldn't trigger (because it's not moving). To track the initial position of the mouse you need to use `mouseover`.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
        console.log(event.clientX);
    }).mousemove(); 
});
```

Check this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/hhL4nroc/

When jou just refresh, the mouse is outside the document so is undefined, when you move it on the document will be tracked.

Comment: Actually, that's not the reason. You can prove that's not the reason by using mouseover instead of mousemove - the mouse IS tracked when you refresh. It's just that the mouse isn't moving so mousemove doesn't fire.